# Is it possible to create a compass in VisionOS?

Tags: swift, geolocation, visionos

I am attempting to create a simple compass for Apple Vision Pro. The method I am familiar with involves using:

```
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
                  didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
```

However, this does not function on visionOS as 'CLHeading is unavailable in visionOS'.

Is there any way to develop this simple compass on visionOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a compass using sensor integration via the OS, that isn't possible.

The framework is supported on vision, but the `CLHeading` is not, per the docs.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading

Vision hardware documents also state there is no GPS features in the initial version.

> Apple Vision Pro doesn’t have GPS functions and supports basic location services. Also consider any potential safety implications of your app on Apple Vision Pro.

https://developer.apple.com/visionos/compatibility-evaluations/

If you are talking about "a compass-like" feature that would let you know what direction you are facing, you might be able to have an app which did it doing local information (like doors and windows). The user would probably to do some manual alignment, but then the visor could take it from there.

Comment: I just want to create a simple compass that indicates north, south, east, and west.